# How to remove the child action in asp.net mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

how can i remove the child action in asp.net mvc3. I mean i am having partial views and main views. In the url bar when i entered the child page then it should not load.

for suppose my main page is

> localhost:5820/Home/Index

Then when i enter

> localhost:5820/Home/Index

then it should work and the child item is

> localhost:5820/Home/About

Then when i enter

> localhost:5820/Home/About

then it should not open. How can i do that in asp.net mvc. I have several pages like that i have displayed the pages in  how can 
i rectify this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that your ABOUT page is a link inside your HOME page does not mean it is a child action, in fact, from the point of view of MVC they are in the same level, is YOU as a programmer that give the ilussion of hiereachies by providing an order of navigation.

Now, what you can do is:

1. simply remove the Action Methods from your controller, or
2. write a simple ignore route like:

   routes.IgnoreRoute("YourRuleToIgnoreActions");

this rules should be at the beginning of your RegisterRoutes method in RegisterRoutes to avoid other rules to be triggered

To build up your ignore rules, here is a nice discussion on the topic: http://ardalis.com/IgnoreRoute-in-ASP.NET-Routing-is-Order-Dependent

***UPDATE***:
Probably too much thinking on this one, but in my opinion, the Models CAN have properties that modify the behaviour of the View, this is because from an architectural point of view, when you are already in the View, your concern is exclusively on the presentation layer, so I think it is perfectly valid to have something like:

```
 public class MyReportsModel{
     public bool displaySection1 { get; set;}
    //other data
 }
```

and in your views, you can change the presentation in the following way:

```
  @{
   if(@Model.displaySection1){
        //display as normal
    }

}
```

Of course, when you populate the model you should set that property in each controller according to your needs:

```
  MyReporstModel thisView = new MyReportsModel();
  thisView.displaySection1 = true;
   // set all properties necessary to display

   // if the controller knows that this partial view won't be displayed then 
    thisView.displaySection1 = false;
```

But that is no longer a technical issue but an architectural one.

hope it helps,

Comment: Alvardo I had just taken an example there. I will be having different controller for different view pages. In the main pages I need to put the partial view. The partial pages should not be loaded like I said above

Comment: Ok, I see, in that case, have you tried addiing some simple logic in your view to change that behavior, for example, a bool property named 'isDisplayed' that you can populate from your controller, so whenever you call that partial view, the view will know how to behave, it could be default value of TRUE, and only on exceptions you set the property to FALSE.

Comment: The way I think of your problem is in the Presentation Layer so in my opinion is perfectly valid to create a model useful to change behaviour on your views.

Comment: how can i set the isDisplayed field

Comment: I updated the answer in case you want to hear my opinion on the issue. let me know what you think about it :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are looking for [`ChildActionOnly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.childactiononlyattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) attribute:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult About()
{
    return View();
}
```

It disables direct calls to `localhost:5820/Home/About` - only rendering as partial view will be available.

*UPDATE* according to what you need - mark all actions which should return partial views with `ChildActionOnly` attribute:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult About()
{
    var model = ...
    return PartialView("_About", model);
}
```

And in index view call those actions (from `Home` controller and other controllers) via:

```
@Html.Action("About", "Home")
```

Comment: +1 from my part,  I didn't know about that one, it comes really handy when you have views that shouldn't be called directly

Comment: @lazyberezovsky exactly what I need. i will explain. I will be having some main page created as view. In that i am using 5 tabs. Each tab should contains 5 tabs. 5 tabs will be having 5 different partial views. Each partial will be having their own controller. In the controller i will give the index method [childactiononly] attribute. but it is getting an exception. My main goal is not to open the page outside. It should be opened only in tab. Hope you understand now.